# Что такое SwingUtilities.invokeLater для swing

Tags: java, swing

Что такое SwingUtilities.invokeLater для swing? И когда лучше его использовать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите.

Обычно поведение UI-фреймворков (например, Swing'а) построено вокруг цикла обработки событий. Всё, что происходит в программе в главном потоке, происходит в одной из итераций этого цикла.

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater` предназначена для запуска асинхронной операции. Она сохраняет действие (`Runnable`), и запускает его на одной из следующих итераций цикла сообщений.

При помощи этого вы можете, например, отложить какую-то операцию на позже. Или если ваш код находится в другом потоке, вы можете «отправить» операцию выполняться в главном UI-потоке.

---

Обратите внимание, что таким образом не стоит выполнять «тяжёлые» операции, т. к. код будет выполнен в UI-потоке, в занимать его надолго не стоит.

Comment: Это мне напомнило android

Comment: С его фитчами, не выполнять действия с интерфейсами в главном потоке.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров: Угу. Но `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, наоборот, доставляет операцию в главный поток. Поэтому не имеет смысла передавать туда что-то длинное.

Comment: Я использую SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { и иногда вылетают Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread как это можно предотврадить, по логике все должно быть хорошо, тоесть оператор дождался выполнения его и продолжил.

Comment: Ну, это совсем другая ситуация. Вам же говорят в ошибке, что произошло. Вы находитесь в главном потоке, и хотите, чтобы функция была вызвана на следующей итерации цикла сообщений. И вы хотите дождаться окончания вызова прям щас. Но если вы будете дожидаться вызова, то вы этим затягиваете окончание этой итерации, так что новая никогда не наступит. Вот вас и предупредили, что вы создаёте deadlock.

Comment: Да, спасибо за помощь, буду постепенно осваивать это, надоело сидеть в варнингах и в непредсказуемости проги.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров: Пожалуйста!