# Постоянное обновление JLabel

Tags: java, swing, дата

Хочу сделать часы на Java (Swing) и тут возникла проблема. Сначала я хотел сделать обновление через бесконечный цикл, но в таком случае происходит зависание программы или бесконечное создание Frame-ов. Сейчас не заю как реализовать, есть предположение что можно сделать через многопоточность. Посоветуйте как мне это сделать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать обратный отсчет времени в java swing?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/966362/204271)

Comment: Вроде как подходит но я не могу разобраться, поможете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример кода

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestSwing extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestSwing jFrame = new TestSwing();
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        //###
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            String nowFormatted = dateTimeFormatter.format(now);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> timeLabel.setText(nowFormatted));
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //###

        jFrame.setSize(300,300);
        jFrame.add(timeLabel);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Ключевые строчки обрамлены в `//###`

`ScheduledExecutorService` используется для того, чтобы раз в секунду (смотри 3 и 4 параметры), начиная с нулевым делеем (смотри 2 параметр) вызывать какое-то действие ( смотри 1 параметр).
В нашем случае действие - взять текущую дату, отформатировать ее и проставить форматированное время в label.

Тут стоит обратить внимание, что нам обязательно нужен метод [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) - потому что мы данные в JLabel обновляем не в Swing потоке( [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476435/177093) чутка детальнее написано про данный метод)

Comment: Спасибо за пример и правильный ответ)