# Как реализовать обновление Label в JavaFX с использованием FXML файла

Tags: java, javafx, swing, fxml

Я переделываю свои программы на *Swing* в программы *JavaFX*. Одна из программ это часы. Суть заключается в том что нужно каждую секунду обновлять Label. Я задавал подробный вопрос только связаный с библиотекой *Swing*, а не *JavaFX*. Вот этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121236/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-jlabel). Я поискал в **Google** решение моей проблемы и наткнулся на метод *Platform.runLater()* и переписал код под него. Она заработала, но я не могу использовать *FXML* файл. Как мне это реализовать?
Также вот код для изменения Label:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Today' dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String nowFormatted = dateTimeFormatter.format(now);
        Platform.runLater(() -> timer.setText(nowFormatted));
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Не понятно, вы не можете использовать FXML потому что не получается? Или это ограничения? В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: Если я использую FXML я не могу контролировать Label, мне выдает NullPointer

Comment: Через Controller я не могу изменять Label т.к. нет такого события

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже что вы делаете что то не так.

1)Нужно связать fxml файл с контроллером. Для этого над классом контроллера нужна аннотация:

```
@ViewController(value = "/fxml/timer.fxml", title = "Таймер")
```

2)В fxml файле указать id для элемента.

```
<Label fx:id="timeLabel" />
```

3)В контроллере определить этот элемент

```
@FXML
private Label timeLabel;
```

Название id и имени переменной должны совпадать, тогда javafx сделает инжект.

4)Можно использовать `@PostConstruct`, метод с этой аннотацией выполнится после создания контроллера.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Today' dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String nowFormatted = dateTimeFormatter.format(now);
        Platform.runLater(() -> timer.setText(nowFormatted));
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Controller у меня подключен и fx:id прописан, проблема в том что я не знаю как и куда встроить мой кусок кода

Comment: Если я пишу в start, то не могу соединить переменную timer, которая и показывает время. В Controller прописываются события, я не знаю, можно ли сделать событие, которое будет вызываться постоянно.

Comment: Логика выполнения должна быть в контроллере. Можно использовать `@PostConstruct`. Повесьте его на метод в контроллере, тогда после того как будет создан контроллер выполнится метод помеченный `@PostConstruct`. В нем и запустите свой шудлер

Comment: То есть метод init будет выполнен после start, когда уже будет создана Scene?

Comment: После start. Нужно определиться, в start у вас создается сцена и возможно какие то еще общие настройки применяются(загрузка шрифтов, стилей и т.д.). Контроллеры это отдельные сущности, их может быть много и  между ними можно переключаться.

Comment: Тогда это решает вопрос, Спасибо

Comment: Мне кажется вы как то не правильно строите свое приложение. 2 путь это идти от fmxl, вот тут пример https://o7planning.org/ru/10623/javafx-tutorial-for-beginners